# Property shows in hibernate trace log with value but value is not mapped to object property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have an Entity class with a number of properties in it.

The properties are properly discovered by Hibernate during the spring boot initialization via the Hibernate AnnotationBinder and values are sourced correctly from our database and properly mapped to to the object via the Hibernate BasicExtractor.

However it seems that when accessing the properties, their values are from a stale cached version. For example, its value is always null, not the value as shown in the extractor logs and I can't seem to figure out why. Of note: I can *save* to this property and have it persist correctly, I just cannot *read* from it

WHTFMain class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "whtf_main")
public class WHTFMain {
     ...
     @Column(nullable = true)
     private String netsuiteId;
     ....
     // getter/setter not shown
 }
```

Annotation Binder Logs:

```
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Processing annotations of com.xxx.modules.netsuite.customRecords.WHTFMain.netsuiteId 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl - Normalizing identifier quoting [netsuiteId] 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl - Normalizing identifier quoting [netsuiteId] 
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(whtf_main), mappingColumn=netsuite_id, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false} 
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property netsuiteId with lazy=false 
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.xxx.modules.netsuite.customRecords.WHTFMain:netsuiteId] 
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for netsuiteId 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl - Normalizing identifier quoting [netsuiteId] 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl - Normalizing identifier quoting [netsuiteId] 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl - Normalizing identifier quoting [netsuiteId] 
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property netsuiteId 
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Cascading netsuiteId with null
```

Basic Extractor Log (503 is the correct value)

```
[ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([netsuite8_1_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [503]
```

Query:

```
public List<WHTFMain> findByMongoId(String mongoId) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select w from WHTFMain w where mongoId = :mongoId", WHTFMain.class)
            .setParameter("mongoId",mongoId)
            .getResultList();
}
```

Called:

```
List<WHTFMain> whtfMainList = whtfDAO.findByMongoId(whtfMain.getMongoId());
```

Inspected:

```
netsuiteId = null
```

Comment: Where are your transaction boundaries? Have you activated logging to see the transaction handling and execution of sql statements?

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks for the nudge - I removed the Transactional annotation form my bean and the value is now propagating as expected. Can you shed some light on why the transactional boundaries would cause this issue to persist?  I had originally discounted it as the issue would occur across multiple runs of the application.

Comment: I don't know what actually happened because I don't know what you did/saw in which transaction. But when people see inconsistent data with DBs/JPA in 9/10 cases it's the transaction/session handling.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks, I will keep that mind. I appreciate it